# Hiding controls from ListView quick edit mode

Tags: 2013, list-view, quick-edit

I am working on a requirement that requires me to disable one field from editing (even in the quick edit mode).  I just want user to add new record and update existing records (except one field).

I am able to achieve something and remove the fields from quick edit,  however i see that on focus of the cell,  quick edit adds a new control (drop down),  has anyone figured out a way to disable that?

Any suggestions...

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you found any  solution for the above issue?

Comment: @light nope i didnt find any solution for this,  i ended up using the code below to disable rows.

Comment: how can I disable specific cell in a row based on value using below code, I'm not able to find that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `AllowGridEditing` with JS Link like this (example with Title):

```
var fieldContext = {
  Templates: {
    Fields: {
      LinkTitle: {
        View: function(ctx, b) {
          b.AllowGridEditing = false;
          return ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
        }        
      }
    }
  }
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
```

Comment: Thanks Eiri,  I would like use to be able to add new records,  just not update the old records.  I assume this script will not let him enter anything for the column.  I will give it a try.

Comment: is there a way we can prevent this template from overriding the last row.

Comment: as expected this is making the field read only for all the rows...I want to either exclude the last row,  or a way of setting value for the disabled field using script.  any pointers

Answer (score 0):

You can use approach used in below blog

http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/

I was exploring it for composite validation purpose. Not working for me. But while implementing same functionality was achieved at cell level for which ever column you want to implement.